# UIPageViewController optimization and possible solution

Tags: objective-c, optimization, uiimage

I am using a `UIPageViewController` in my app to display number of images (1024x768 size). Is it ok to make array of `UIViewControllers` each with his picture and in set appropriate for each page? Maybe if you get like 50 pictures it will crash? At the moment I store images in Documents folder so I can remove images from view controllers that are not on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be very efficient, you'd be much better off doing the same thing with `UIImageViews`. Even then you have to be careful. Probably the best way to handle this would be to using image views and deallocating them when they go more than one image width out of the screens bounds. Then of course reallocing when the image in question is the next image in line to be displayed in either direction.

**EDIT:** It looks like you can use the following UIPageViewController Datasource methods to set which view controller do basically have queued and waiting to the right/left. Using these you should be able to only allocate 3 view controllers at a time.

```
– pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:
– pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:
```

Then you can use this to set the initial controller:

Set the initial view controller using UIPageViewController's

```
-setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:
```

The sentence below is quoted from Apple's documentation and is leading me to believe that the controller may be able to only load the necessary view controllers into memory on its own.

> View controllers are either provided one at a time (or two at a time,
>   depending upon the spine position and double-sided state) via the
>   setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method, or provided
>   as-needed by the data source. Gesture-based navigation is enabled only
>   when a data source is provided.

Comment: Thanks! I ll try to deallocate then. But I think I cant place UIImageView in PageController since it asks for ViewControllers..

Comment: @ValentinKhrulkov Oh you mean a `UIPageViewController` in your post you said a `UIPageControl`, which refers to the horizontal scrolling controller with the dots at the bottom.

Comment: Oh yes, UIPageViewController, sorry

Comment: Any other ideas due to this then?

Comment: Awesome! 1 more question: if i create say 20 view controllers and store them in array,but not yet add them to screen,will they take huge part of memory?

Comment: @ValentinKhrulkov As far as I know the only part of an object that is allocated in an array would be the string values of the names of the objects.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think there is a cache for the previous and next viewController. Because my zoomed images keep their size only if I don't go to page +2 or page -2